# Delete an object using jpa remove

Tags: jpa

Please can someone help me out.

ManagedBean

```
public Customer deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
    BookstoreManager.getInstance().deleteCustomer(customer);
    System.out.println("Customer deleted" + customer.getFirstName());
    return  null;
}
```

Business Logik

```
public Customer deleteCustomer(Customer deletedCustomer) {
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        em.remove(customer);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Hello from delete");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error Message

> Info: HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing

Comment: Why are you instantiate a new customer in your deleteCustomer method ? this cause the error, just pass the one in method parameter

Comment: Your answer was the solution. Thanks Abass A.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `em.remove(deletedCustomer);`?

```
public Customer deleteCustomer(Customer deletedCustomer) {
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(deletedCustomer);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Hello from delete");
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can only remove a entity with state managed.
[image]

Source http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Jklee.